# How is x84 code different from Arm code. Don't you just need a new compiler?

Tags: compiler-construction, arm64

I am new at Programming and I asked myself what „Arm optimised Apps“ mean. And what’s the difference between non optimised Apps. Wouldn‘t it be enough to make a new compiler so that the same code could be used for both architectures?
I would be afraid if you can give me some background information.
Thank you in advance

Comment: In principle yes, you just need to compile it for the correct platform. But often the devil is in the details. Depending on the language, for instance the size if an `int` might not be standardized, so different compilers might use different sizes, and if you depend on certain properties of a datatype (min/max values, number of bytes ...), you might get problems

Comment: What's x84?  Typo for x86 or x64?

Comment: You might also want to make some parts more efficient than the compiler is able to optimize, so you could write those parts in assembly language, or with CPU intrinsics.  Those would need to be rewritten for each new architecture.

Comment: By itself "Arm optimised Apps" is just a buzzword that doesn't mean anything.  What's the context?  Where did you see it?

Comment: @nate: i believe it refers to an app actually compiled for the ARM platform, as opposed to being compiled for x86 and converted to ARM code by using an ["emulator"'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/apps-on-arm-x86-emulation), which is really a binary-to-binary JIT trans coder. See also Rosetta 2 (or the original Rosetta).